# git subtree push fails with fatal:bad object

Tags: git

I have repro my commands with other repos and they work, here I am having the following issue:

```
git subtree push --prefix=GRE GREFromPartner IntegrationBranch
```

fails with:

```
89 (73)fatal: bad object f8f24a7d624e2...
```

I tried to pull the remote in, merge and push, but no solution, same issue.
If I ask:

```
$ git show f8f24a7d624e26ccbabfd4ea549bc01350273e9f
fatal: bad object f8f24a7d624e26ccbabfd4ea549bc01350273e9f
```

The checkin f8f2 does not appear to be in the parent or child repo (I am using SourceTree Jump to function for this, dunno how to verify from command line)

fsck shows me the following:

```
$ git fsck
Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
Checking objects: 100% (269106/269106), done.
dangling blob b22d7030bd9f9992bea966cb8c3cc87e9dc8b14f
dangling blob 633b30ef1555cb24a26bcea3cb949cee77f3c47d
dangling blob d6e948169bac17aeb378e389603cc6c35d102edd
dangling blob d6fb10b30b71efdb58c1d5a143529632ee824072
dangling commit c808890bc4e89959ca84d564374fbe4697a03464
dangling blob 4e11d171833d4084ecdb4498be5ed7f65b414a40
dangling blob f917e9a6af4cf869ef60b56e8e50e5732b5ad1e1
dangling blob 2a2d692a4059629afa53d4781d4d5075256b98e7
dangling blob d24ad9e44a75f05a2d31478a8c6fbd6e7b3779e3
dangling blob 65f5c986a106f5894412678d57a7f3ea26a7477d
dangling blob 2e1eba36694c547f05729ae5994bed2ece7f96d0
dangling blob abc3c2b7ab2f2dfceaa6e4b644802547cf062d15
dangling blob baddea14dfa764a199ce1d377b65178846cafe93
dangling blob 425d037bc66af40e87397039fa23e9a1303c76dd
dangling blob b197ab8062a191b8bf93f8d6361711aff1e1799f
dangling commit a89c53a40c1b3480cfb16b7ca7fd2827a3e362cf
dangling blob 7dc1e3d9c6abea67d7efa19a69bfbf71910ac90c
dangling blob 8fc1eb6da860f4c8d180591fb48a2f9c92dcb47d
dangling blob 31ed2bc1d1972a351395e9b7b4b14084f03e7223
dangling blob fc154ca9a76fd3e198672a5d7838599fa6a300bf
dangling blob c41fa482f75b71a11e974c96f6ee468152a98bfa
dangling blob 88831c7a1227e39ee8c6ec3f5f17e569e2b1223f
dangling blob 3c9284b1fb7abb90d0582555b349e439227481a2
dangling blob d4934c3755400b1920f9a65444123b301c750d58
dangling blob 7dbadc54722fc2e5d8c0831fc1b5a1f66eb6c521
dangling blob 39d334f0c53fe1fea17b85ff5288b4e12e2aed25
dangling commit 68d6acddc412235ccb4ecdeac435874e145ac49a
dangling tag b6f96ce16f21eb6b5f40e199f28f94e21ab93309
dangling blob cdf91c2927d5d2a090a4712bbb5519002cb72d14
dangling blob 870e4503dc6cec51b8b061015ed5582da45b79e1
dangling blob ed1d9511812e42a87efae3671c33ab2f5f7c2d86
dangling blob fd398d12b7074154347777626a48884826f4a2e3
dangling blob c344d522143e1c0175e4a600fe475dfa903eb436
dangling blob 3a89eda591e9f804121408bc0f3ca30d4358629e
dangling blob 01ad4d6d1668280217b988c35ebe379dbacd8dad
dangling blob ef3116653d6db1e6de1dc1442daecbd08a10cb20
dangling blob 1445a62ae1a1cab26062f293318d39be4c5a893f
dangling blob b85c8e71793a59e6bec6032590755759001b1608
dangling blob 8075b61f605f3deb3c1a389a301f3ca0d02c022c
dangling blob 9d90b6d337c96c45b83b12d9c7698b8dadc488c4
dangling tag c7a72e44f8e088c337c8a5a6f196f9cc89bc4f31
dangling blob b3b1ee96591a44a7b4eecf58c6691d2ee414d280
dangling blob 32b806ea52cb4b30d1ef517109ff16604fb9ed47
dangling blob 79cbfe71fc0a7d80f1ca38feee9542b52f5f57d3
dangling blob b0db06497864d3c1dabb49b61ac454f4b5183f98
dangling blob b9de4e0e11c47c7291e4d946f1c5ba3037c4d474
dangling commit 85f7ce0edee892dee791ea65c4ba32caac723850
dangling blob 82413f7ea499401e8f0bc29c0a078193ea6323ec
dangling blob 405cd7bb9bfa7fd186babe95f9174ced4c58c211
dangling blob ec60170c8f3f3cb25803970cde20477582b6da8a
dangling blob d5674ffbe21008d75b85db65efa7875fd2c6c956
dangling blob 62caf7adf04f219eee73acfd5fedd20c2a33ac77
dangling blob 87f9e704603524e17be82ddbe0db0355ddaa5896
```

I found the following:
the last merge checkin has the following info (in SourceTree):

```
Commit: 0550273d38bb48a3b37b0376800c2795c26da9b9 [0550273]
Parents: a8d1ce7edd
Author: Mauro.Giusti <Mauro.Giusti@Wizards.com>
Date: Thursday, November 5, 2015 5:35:45 PM
Squashed 'GRE/' changes from f8f24a7..a3e2b17


git-subtree-dir: GRE
git-subtree-split: a3e2b178e8e0f4ae6e2c641d3594277cb96f2e4f
```

I think that happened when I called:

```
git subtree pull --prefix=GRE --squash GREFromPartner GRE.Net_ThreadingIssue
```

If I see the parent of this checkin says:

```
Commit: a8d1ce7eddc78b1b957a2b3b63385685fe4bce44 [a8d1ce7]
Parents: b4a4fad275
Author: perrasc <v-craig.perras@wizards.com>
Date: Wednesday, October 21, 2015 1:17:51 PM
Squashed 'GRE/' changes from 82be720..f8f24a7

f8f24a7 merge Mauro's changes (10/20)
..... other checkins
```

But the f8f2 checkin is not in this repo or the parent one (GREFromPartner)

Help! I am about to copy file on the file system to be able to move on :(

Thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I think I know what the issue is - 
The checkin f8f2 was in the Partner depo i was pulling, but in a different dangling branch that was not merged into the branch that I recently pulled.
I merged the changes on the Partner depo, pulled changes, merged and pushed back no issues :)